# How do I change the width of an element using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

How do I change `width` value assigned in `#center`? (I don't want to switch between CSS files just because 1 changed `width` value.) How do I dynamically change the value using Javascript?

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
<style type="text/css">
    #main #center {
        width: 600px; // change width to 700 on click
        float: left;
    }

    #main #center .send {
        background: #fff;
        padding: 10px;
        position: relative;
    }

    #main #center .send .music {
        text-align: center;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
    }

    #main #center .send .write {
        font-family: georgia, serif;
        font-size: 150px;
        opacity: 0.2;
    }

    //....etc.
</style>
</head>

<body>
    // change #center width to 700
    <a href="#go2" onclick="how to change width of #center ???" ></a> 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
document.getElementById('center').style.width = "599px";
```

Answer (score 2):

Two possible ways:

1. Give the element "center" a class value that matches another CSS rule
2. Alter the "style" property of the element

Answer (score 2):

```
document.getElementById( 'center' ).style.width = "700px";
```

Answer (score 0):

Call a javascript function in the onclick which takes the dom element and sets the new width OR changes the class of the element

```
function changeWidth(){
  document.getElementById('center');
  div.style.width="1270px";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div onclick="changeWidth()" id="main">
Stuff
</div>

<div onclick="changeWidth()" id="center">
More Stuff
</div>

function changeWidth(){
   this.style.width = "700px";
}
```